# scrheadings and longtable not working together

Tags: table-of-contents, longtable, koma-script

I need pretty urgent help (thesis hits the printer in two days!) getting `scrheadings` and `longtable` working together.

The problem is if I have `scrheadings` enabled, the `longtable` tables will not align properly, regardless of how many times I rerun `pdflatex` on it. The `longtable` documentation does not mention anything about incompatibility with KOMA-Script or `scrheadings`. However, KOMA-Script documentation does make note of that `longtable` captions can be iffy, and has a special "`origlongtable`" option, but this did not work for me, and the captions are not my problem to begin with, as it looks fine to me.

Doing a search I found that I'm not the first to stumble into it (I think), but no coherent question (and thus no answer) was offered by previous reporter:
 [scrheadings-and-longtable-alignment-problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112509/scrheadings-and-longtable-alignment-problems), and [longtable-column-problem-column-alignment-changes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98691/longtable-column-problem-column-alignment-changes/). Also, this mailing list, alas, in German: [scrheadings-und-grosze-tabellen](http://de.comp.text.tex.narkive.com/3PooeoGM/scrheadings-und-grosze-tabellen).

I have spent many hours hunting the cause for this, and I have desperately tried to make a MWE, but things are not easy since I don't understand TeX code. I could not figure out how to make it not depend on `classicthesis.sty`, so I had to include that as well, but in a version that I cut out a lot of (to me unintelligible) TeX-code.

I note the following:

- If I comment out the `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` the `longtable` will align just fine. Same goes for the ToC: `\include{contents}`, it seems. So what on earth is going on here?

My current plan is to compile two versions of my thesis, one to get the TOC and one for the correctly aligned `longtable`s, and then splice the PDFs together. Desperate solution for a poor desperate PhD-student. If the above is not solvable, could one issue some command before and after the `longtable` to make `scrheadings` stop messing up my tables?

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[headinclude,9pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american,swedish]{babel}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

% Commenting out one or both of the below 2 lines will make longtable work again.
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\include{contents}

\scriptsize
\begin{longtable}[l]{rrrrrrrr}
$1$       & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ & $8$ \\
\hline
\endhead
$5.314$   & $1.022$   & $6.962$   & $4.835$   & $9.946$   & $9.707$   & $9.971$   & $9.964$    \\
$7.175$   & $9.866$   & $4.687$   & $9.776$   & $8.412$   & $7.882$   & $7.139$   & $1.155$    \\
$1.96$    & $5.353$   & $1$       & $5.004$   & $4.883$   & $9.988$   & $2.672$   & $1.112$    \\
$8.874$   & $2.278$   & $2.459$   & $1.371$   & $2.25$    & $1.821$   & $1.04$    & $1$        \\
$1.528$   & $5.917$   & $1$       & $9.246$   & $1.73$    & $1.005$   & $9.33$    & $8.058$    \\
$3.014$   & $4.365$   & $6.927$   & $9.413$   & $7.008$   & $9.914$   & $2.72$    & $9.866$    \\
$5.673$   & $3.747$   & $11.45$   & $1.182$   & $3.794$   & $3.458$   & $1.028$   & $1.24$     \\
$1.395$   & $2.384$   & $2.638$   & $5.219$   & $3.087$   & $2.826$   & $4.889$   & $3.528$    \\
$8.556$   & $4.747$   & $1.171$   & $7.636$   & $9.789$   & $3.979$   & $0.01852$ & $9.399$    \\
$3.422$   & $16.3$    & $5.842$   & $94.55$   & $0.1007$  & $0.1002$  & $0.1057$  & $0.1001$   \\
$0.1532$  & $0.1$     & $0.1$     & $0.1183$  & $0.1001$  & $0.1001$  & $0.1002$  & $0.1001$   \\
$25.77$   & $0.4728$  & $96.91$   & $275.3$   & $41.25$   & $31.46$   & $1.286$   & $176.2$    \\
$12.27$   & $35.94$   & $23.2$    & $231.6$   & $2.785$   & $0.4538$  & $13.76$   & $12.07$    \\
$1.753$   & $2.225$   & $1.867$   & $1.574$   & $1.401$   & $1.785$   & $0.3183$  & $1.026$    \\
$30.75$   & $0.5885$  & $153.7$   & $363.5$   & $47.7$    & $39.29$   & $2.544$   & $396.5$    \\
$9.981$   & $21.8$    & $11.88$   & $81.95$   & $3.601$   & $0.01082$ & $26.78$   & $11.29$    \\
$1.941$   & $2.086$   & $1.59$    & $1.066$   & $1.232$   & $2.428$   & $1.6$     & $1.102$    \\
$4.987$   & $6.033$   & $3.409$   & $3.455$   & $4.937$   & $10.59$   & $15.17$   & $1.303$    \\
$44.99$   & $1.053$   & $142.6$   & $443.7$   & $58.63$   & $35.93$   & $4.415$   & $326.5$    \\
$3.904$   & $12.66$   & $8.865$   & $0.1209$  & $1.807$   & $0.3359$  & $94.19$   & $17.22$    \\
$5.344$   & $6.743$   & $18.56$   & $4.354$   & $5.036$   & $10.07$   & $6.786$   & $11.3$     \\
$9.74$    & $0.1519$  & $52.48$   & $82.46$   & $13.34$   & $8.783$   & $0.9119$  & $84.15$    \\
$2.25$    & $5.199$   & $41.75$   & $0.3816$  & $1.775$   & $0.8467$  & $61.33$   & $14.62$    \\
$41.94$   & $1.205$   & $291.2$   & $493.8$   & $63.51$   & $22.02$   & $3.123$   & $385.8$    \\
$15.93$   & $16.24$   & $26.48$   & $12.24$   & $12.13$   & $11.21$   & $7.592$   & $29.8$     \\
$0.109$   & $0.1465$  & $0.1458$  & $0.4281$  & $0.6299$  & $0.01341$ & $0.2518$  & $12.3$     \\
$3.336$   & $5.127$   & $3.068$   & $2.549$   & $1.704$   & $13.25$   & $2.484$   & $4.045$    \\
$56.5$    & $1.971$   & $182.5$   & $150.7$   & $33.31$   & $93.73$   & $6.552$   & $725.3$    \\
$3.28$    & $7.1$     & $4.992$   & $4.912$   & $2.576$   & $4.767$   & $4.378$   & $3.856$    \\
$4.315$   & $16.33$   & $10.8$    & $54.31$   & $4.513$   & $0.106$   & $18.25$   & $0.101$    \\
$41.19$   & $1.027$   & $156.9$   & $365.3$   & $43.43$   & $39$      & $2.794$   & $368.7$    \\
$4.774$   & $5.466$   & $4.54$    & $3.558$   & $4.259$   & $6.963$   & $3.439$   & $4.691$    \\
$1.34$    & $6.864$   & $4.343$   & $1.108$   & $2.083$   & $0.4267$  & $17.04$   & $7.185$    \\
$5.91$    & $8.392$   & $8.667$   & $4.178$   & $3.885$   & $11.58$   & $4.722$   & $7.319$    \\
$0.2745$  & $0.1423$  & $0.1$     & $1.732$   & $0.7494$  & $0.1001$  & $0.1002$  & $0.1$      \\
$1.411$   & $2.714$   & $6.728$   & $0.5166$  & $0.5525$  & $3.9$     & $0.2139$  & $0.1194$   \\
$0.03975$ & $0.01041$ & $0.2149$  & $0.1999$  & $1.944$   & $0.3978$  & $2.477$   & $2.029$    \\
$6.967$   & $4.775$   & $1.069$   & $7.782$   & $10.91$   & $3.516$   & $0.1142$  & $0.04042$  \\
$0.7146$  & $0.9026$  & $0.03532$ & $0.5893$  & $0.06372$ & $0.1207$  & $0.1105$  & $0.8943$   \\
$2.874$   & $0.05704$ & $1.302$   & $0.1891$  & $1.021$   & $1.025$   & $9.955$   & $6.847$    \\
$0.06041$ & $0.02929$ & $0.2607$  & $0.1446$  & $0.03939$ & $0.02616$ & $9.917$   & $0.02871$  \\
$0.08923$ & $0.49$    & $0.5084$  & $2.492$   & $8.706$   & $1.344$   & $0.02061$ & $0.01041$  \\
$9.958$   & $0.554$   & $0.01093$ & $0.5246$  & $0.1416$  & $0.04229$ & $0.1703$  & $0.08021$  \\
$3.887$   & $0.05062$ & $0.3151$  & $0.1267$  & $0.1986$  & $0.6058$  & $0.9035$  & $0.3665$   \\
$1.422$   & $1.051$   & $0.2785$  & $1.016$   & $2.263$   & $1.208$   & $1.681$   & $5.28$     \\
$1.856$   & $0.3341$  & $0.3861$  & $0.6126$  & $2.295$   & $1.034$   & $9.883$   & $2.965$    \\
$0.06021$ & $0.409$   & $0.1273$  & $0.4442$  & $0.4195$  & $0.09476$ & $0.3549$  & $0.04486$  \\
$0.02732$ & $2.021$   & $0.01001$ & $0.01015$ & $0.02322$ & $0.07358$ & $7.587$   & $2.726$    \\
$0.2654$  & $0.03313$ & $4.774$   & $48.57$   & $1.886$   & $6.904$   & $0.01097$ & $3.993$    \\
$0.2687$  & $0.1$     & $0.1848$  & $5.627$   & $0.1$     & $0.187$   & $0.6628$  & $1.854$    \\
$0.2899$  & $0.3853$  & $0.2802$  & $0.4432$  & $0.353$   & $0.2547$  & $0.2058$  & $0.4459$   \\
$0.08977$ & $0.2525$  & $0.03518$ & $0.08095$ & $1.744$   & $0.0169$  & $0.09316$ & $0.2516$   \\
$0.2518$  & $1.103$   & $1.484$   & $0.6334$  & $3.107$   & $6.618$   & $0.5109$  & $0.1847$   \\
$0.112$   & $0.5891$  & $0.6062$  & $1.099$   & $2.985$   & $1.76$    & $0.2073$  & $0.9535$   \\
$3.772$   & $0.2317$  & $13.31$   & $0.1221$  & $0.2228$  & $0.3602$  & $0.6104$  & $3.268$    \\
$28.34$   & $0.1472$  & $1.198$   & $3.449$   & $0.1286$  & $0.5261$  & $0.1402$  & $2.619$    \\
$2.543$   & $0.8543$  & $1.947$   & $0.9492$  & $0.1006$  & $1.171$   & $3.011$   & $3.302$    \\
$0.6127$  & $0.996$   & $0.7966$  & $0.6529$  & $0.4437$  & $0.6407$  & $0.5032$  & $0.7201$   \\
$0.6154$  & $0.5889$  & $0.472$   & $0.6059$  & $0.5981$  & $0.5305$  & $0.3759$  & $0.4505$   \\
$0.4322$  & $0.3761$  & $0.4737$  & $0.5013$  & $0.5489$  & $0.5424$  & $0.4513$  & $0.5409$   \\
$1.869$   & $2.3$     & $0.5026$  & $0.9276$  & $0.8059$  & $0.6966$  & $0.5001$  & $0.961$    \\
$0.451$   & $0.0133$  & $0.1935$  & $0.05858$ & $2.764$   & $0.03575$ & $0.01039$ & $0.01$     \\
$1.277$   & $0.6487$  & $0.6006$  & $0.6056$  & $0.6031$  & $0.7777$  & $0.7167$  & $0.6031$   \\
$0.1$     & $5.437$   & $3.417$   & $5.527$   & $2.369$   & $2.336$   & $4.77$    & $0.5255$   \\
$0.1886$  & $0.1225$  & $0.3288$  & $0.2881$  & $0.07189$ & $0.1356$  & $0.01001$ & $0.03257$  \\
$0.01001$ & $0.01001$ & $0.01$    & $0.01087$ & $0.2276$  & $0.01072$ & $3.854$   & $0.2368$   \\
$0.7611$  & $0.6771$  & $0.6066$  & $0.7547$  & $1.042$   & $1.191$   & $0.5066$  & $0.8838$   \\
$2.57$    & $1.988$   & $2.987$   & $2.085$   & $1.146$   & $2.72$    & $1.726$   & $1.597$    \\
$0.6654$  & $0.376$   & $0.6748$  & $0.2103$  & $0.3006$  & $0.6107$  & $0.2658$  & $0.2214$   \\
$0.5015$  & $4.916$   & $0.5044$  & $3.482$   & $0.5081$  & $0.5002$  & $0.6408$  & $0.5017$   \\
$0.1791$  & $0.09303$ & $0.1774$  & $0.2039$  & $0.241$   & $0.2177$  & $0.2261$  & $0.1897$   \\
$0.5383$  & $0.5828$  & $0.4082$  & $0.6494$  & $2.579$   & $2.917$   & $1.366$   & $0.2781$   \\
$0.07499$ & $0.04744$ & $0.108$   & $0.1645$  & $0.1993$  & $0.1999$  & $0.07084$ & $0.1023$   \\
$4.505$   & $2.426$   & $1.549$   & $2.13$    & $2.219$   & $1.41$    & $1.211$   & $1.192$    \\
$0.3007$  & $0.3012$  & $0.3003$  & $0.3006$  & $0.3002$  & $2.409$   & $0.3835$  & $0.4269$   \\
$0.08544$ & $0.1764$  & $0.09547$ & $0.1197$  & $0.0651$  & $0.03943$ & $0.08041$ & $0.07392$  \\
$1.5$     & $2.848$   & $4.21$    & $1.874$   & $2.577$   & $5.882$   & $1.152$   & $7.667$    \\
$0.6526$  & $0.4176$  & $0.2553$  & $0.4625$  & $0.08625$ & $0.3877$  & $0.1015$  & $0.0686$   \\
$1.032$   & $1.57$    & $0.7937$  & $0.8424$  & $1.04$    & $0.3001$  & $0.7549$  & $0.6028$   \\
$0.0382$  & $0.02757$ & $0.02349$ & $0.4466$  & $7.57$    & $8.143$   & $9.986$   & $1.737$    \\
$0.01001$ & $0.01$    & $0.01$    & $0.05984$ & $0.168$   & $0.01032$ & $0.01$    & $0.03227$  \\
$4.949$   & $5.491$   & $3.84$    & $5.204$   & $7.242$   & $1.795$   & $9.875$   & $3.856$    \\
$9.998$   & $5.681$   & $6.275$   & $8.609$   & $6.993$   & $3.588$   & $9.996$   & $5.083$    \\
$0.1561$  & $0.1115$  & $0.2087$  & $0.8513$  & $0.2252$  & $0.1086$  & $0.1061$  & $0.1566$   \\
$0.9413$  & $0.9188$  & $1.184$   & $6.928$   & $6.751$   & $1.56$    & $0.7253$  & $5.421$    \\
$0.506$   & $0.5711$  & $0.5108$  & $0.5072$  & $0.502$   & $9.773$   & $0.5003$  & $0.5017$   \\
$0.01001$ & $0.9391$  & $0.03945$ & $0.01014$ & $0.6989$  & $2.776$   & $0.03128$ & $0.01007$  \\
$1.774$   & $7.975$   & $0.07585$ & $25.38$   & $9.964$   & $44.21$   & $0.2389$  & $0.1916$   \\
$0.2001$  & $0.216$   & $0.2012$  & $0.2854$  & $0.2021$  & $1.619$   & $0.202$   & $0.447$    \\
$0.9229$  & $0.3759$  & $0.2279$  & $0.456$   & $0.1023$  & $0.09626$ & $0.3508$  & $0.3184$   \\
$1.139$   & $0.5214$  & $0.03266$ & $0.05359$ & $0.07754$ & $0.06792$ & $0.02179$ & $0.001505$ \\
$0.6769$  & $0.3577$  & $0.4285$  & $1.443$   & $4.363$   & $0.3769$  & $0.4726$  & $0.4493$   \\
$0.8039$  & $0.7944$  & $9.998$   & $1.633$   & $5.051$   & $0.8805$  & $6.154$   & $8.512$    \\
$5.273$   & $0.7541$  & $0.9665$  & $0.8438$  & $0.7331$  & $0.5034$  & $0.7004$  & $2.599$    \\
$0.2466$  & $0.1293$  & $0.1668$  & $0.1838$  & $0.2269$  & $0.1458$  & $0.2496$  & $0.2389$   \\
$1.912$   & $1.78$    & $0.6623$  & $0.684$   & $3.208$   & $0.4549$  & $1.356$   & $1.939$    \\
$0.1211$  & $0.4024$  & $0.1647$  & $0.2261$  & $0.1254$  & $0.3022$  & $0.1949$  & $0.1181$   \\
$1.011$   & $1.461$   & $3.951$   & $14.66$   & $5.237$   & $29.92$   & $11.17$   & $29.93$    \\
$1.003$   & $1.111$   & $1.004$   & $1.213$   & $4.415$   & $4.268$   & $4.768$   & $1.017$    \\
$1.061$   & $2.13$    & $1.187$   & $1.622$   & $8.092$   & $1.104$   & $1.66$    & $3.725$    \\
$10.18$   & $25.2$    & $5.827$   & $23.91$   & $3.122$   & $19.15$   & $3.93$    & $5.9$      \\
$0.2607$  & $0.1217$  & $0.5518$  & $0.3$     & $0.9744$  & $1.543$   & $1.358$   & $0.5445$   \\
$0.4659$  & $0.2873$  & $0.312$   & $1.13$    & $1.225$   & $1.666$   & $9.682$   & $2.453$    \\
\caption{\textbf{Foo bar}
}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The TOC that I include

```
% Table of Contents
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents
```

With the classicthesis.sty:

```
% ********************************************************************
% classicthesis.sty
%
% Copyright (C) 2008 André Miede http://www.miede.de
%
% If you like the style then I would appreciate a postcard. My address
% can be found in the file ClassicThesis.pdf. A collection of the
% postcards I received so far is available online at
% http://postcards.miede.de
%
% ********************************************************************
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{classicthesis}[2008/10/01 v2.5 Typographic Style for a classic-looking thesis]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
    \newboolean{@listsseparated} % toggles the vertical space between lof/lot entries of different chapters
    \newboolean{@nochapters} % disable all chapter-specific commands
    \newboolean{@parts} % use part division for the text
    \newboolean{@minionpro} % setup for minion pro font
    \newboolean{@minionprospacing} % use minion pro's textssc for letter spacing
    \newboolean{@pdfspacing} % use pdftex for letterspacing (via microtype)

\RequirePackage{mparhack} % get marginpar right
\RequirePackage[smaller]{acronym} % nice macros for handling all acronyms in the thesis

% ********************************************************************
% Options
% ********************************************************************
\DeclareOption{listsseparated}{\setboolean{@listsseparated}{true}}
\DeclareOption{parts}{\setboolean{@parts}{true}}
\DeclareOption{minionpro}{\setboolean{@minionpro}{true}}
\DeclareOption{minionprospacing}{\setboolean{@minionprospacing}{true}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

% ********************************************************************
% Fancy Stuff
% ********************************************************************
\RequirePackage{booktabs} % for better rules in tables
\RequirePackage{textcase} % for \MakeTextUppercase

\ifthenelse{\boolean{@minionprospacing}}%
    {%
        \PackageInfo{classicthesis}{Using MinionPro's textssc for character spacing.}%
        \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\textssc{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}%
        \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textssc{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}%
    }{%
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{@pdfspacing}}%
        {%
            \PackageInfo{classicthesis}{Using pdftex/microtype for character spacing.%
                                        Make sure your pdftex is version 1.40 or higher.}%
            \microtypesetup{expansion=false}%
            \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\textls[160]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}%
            \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textls[80]{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}%
            \DeclareRobustCommand{\spaced}[1]{\textls[120]{#1}}%
        }{%
            \RequirePackage{soul} % for letterspacing
                \sodef\allcapsspacing{\upshape}{0.15em}{0.65em}{0.6em}%
                \sodef\lowsmallcapsspacing{\scshape}{0.075em}{0.5em}{0.6em}%
                \sodef\spacedspacing{}{0.075em}{0.5em}{0.6em}%
                \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\MakeTextUppercase{\allcapsspacing{#1}}}%
                \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\MakeTextLowercase{\textsc{\lowsmallcapsspacing{#1}}}}%
                \DeclareRobustCommand{\spaced}[1]{\spacedspacing{#1}}%
        }%
    }

% ********************************************************************
% headlines
% ********************************************************************
\RequirePackage[automark]{scrpage2} % provides headers and footers (KOMA Script)
    \clearscrheadings
    \setheadsepline{0pt}
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@nochapters}}%
        {\relax}%
        {
          \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
            \ifthenelse{\value{paper}>0}%
            {\markleft{\textit{Paper \Roman{paper}}}}%: #1}}}
            {\markleft{\textit{#1}}}
          }%
        }
        %\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
        \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textit{#1}}}
        \lehead{\mbox{\llap{\thepage\kern2em}}\leftmark\hfil}
        %\lehead{\thepage}
        %\cehead{\leftmark}
        \rohead{\mbox{\hfil{\rightmark}\rlap{\kern2em\thepage}}}
        %\rohead{\thepage}
        %\cohead{\rightmark}
        \renewcommand{\headfont}{\rm\small}
        %\DeclareRobustCommand{\fixBothHeadlines}[1]{} % <--- ToDo
        % hack to get the content headlines right (thanks, Lorenzo!)
        \def\toc@heading{%
          \ifthenelse{\boolean{@nochapters}}%
                     {\section*{\contentsname}}%nochapters
                     {\chapter*{\contentsname}}%chapters
                     \@mkboth{\textit{\contentsname}}{\textit{\contentsname}}}
```

And Makefile:

```
all: test.tex contents.tex classicthesis.sty
    latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -interactive=nonstopmode -file-line-error" $<

clean:
    latexmk -c

.PHONY: all clean test
```

Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, your my only hope!

PS. From my .log file I appear to have:

- `longtable` 2004/02/01 v4.11
- `scrreprt` 2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA
  (and an older now cut down version of classicthesis.sty)

Comment: Try to remove the \spacedlowsmallcaps from the \markboth command (which imho miss a brace).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So sorry. The missing "}" is my fault when posting, original code had the brace. (I haven't figured out how to edit my original post yet.). Removing the entire line `\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}` does not fix the issue, nor `\markboth{\contentsname}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this undoes anything vital, but it seems to resolve the immediate issue. Starting from [Ulrike Fischer's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303500/scrheadings-and-longtable-not-working-together#comment735724_303500) I replaced the section `Fancy stuff` in `classicthesis.sty` with the following:

```
% ********************************************************************
% Fancy Stuff
% ********************************************************************
\RequirePackage{booktabs} % for better rules in tables
\RequirePackage{textcase} % for \MakeTextUppercase


\RequirePackage{soul} % for letterspacing
\sodef\allcapsspacing{\upshape}{0.15em}{0.65em}{0.6em}%
\sodef\lowsmallcapsspacing{\scshape}{0.075em}{0.5em}{0.6em}%
\sodef\spacedspacing{}{0.075em}{0.5em}{0.6em}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\MakeTextUppercase{\allcapsspacing{#1}}}%
% \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\MakeTextLowercase{\textsc{\lowsmallcapsspacing{#1}}}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\MakeTextLowercase{\textsc{{#1}}}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spaced}[1]{\spacedspacing{#1}}%
```

Mostly, this simply deletes conditional code you're not using. The crucial change is the replacement of the commented line with the line below it which produces

[image: aligned long table]

when the missing curly bracket is supplied in `contents.tex`:

```
% Table of Contents
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents
```

So

```
\sodef\lowsmallcapsspacing{\scshape}{0.075em}{0.5em}{0.6em}%
```

seems to be problematic. If there are other issues associated with the relevant commands, it would be worth looking at whether

```
\sodef\allcapsspacing{\upshape}{0.15em}{0.65em}{0.6em}%
```

and

```
\sodef\spacedspacing{}{0.075em}{0.5em}{0.6em}%
```

are causing trouble as well.

Comment: Hey, thanks, that seemed to have fixed it! But I'm not so sure I wasn't using the code that was removed, as I have (in the full version of the style): `\DeclareOption{minionprospacing}{\setboolean{@minionprospacing}{true}}` and
`\DeclareOption{pdfspacing}{\setboolean{@pdfspacing}{true}}`, so I suspect I am using the coditional code blocks?

Comment: @JohanA Did you know that `classicthesis` seems like a good idea, but is actually quite tricky to deal with as soon as you want the slightest change? I cannot recomment using it.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks, yes, I've noticed. If I had more time (weeks/months), I'd easily go for a more manual approach and write it from scratch, where I understand the code better, but, things being the way they are, at the end of a phd.

Comment: @JohanA Do you actually declare those options? Do you pass the option `minionprospacing` or `pdfspacing` to the package? I just removed the code you didn't seem to be using to simplify things. Just make the changes to whichever code block you actually need if that's different in your actual document.

Comment: @JohanA Just `\DeclareOption...` declares an option It doesn't activate it. That is, it doesn't actually set the boolean to true. It just says: if this option is chosen, then set this boolean to true. If you never set the option, the boolean is never set to true. (At least, it is never set to true by this code.)

Comment: @Johannes_B While I agree about `classicthesis`, two days before your PhD thesis goes to the printer is not the time to ditch the package, whatever its many shortcomings. Especially not if this is the only problem. I certainly wouldn't recommend trying to replace `classicthesis` at this point in the absence of overwhelming reason. (For example, if it blocked compilation when the last chapter was included for some reason and getting rid of it was the only option, you'd have to. But for something like this, I'd tweak and vow never to use such a package again!)

Comment: @cfr I wasn't suggesting to replace it in this occurence. It was a general template related statement. I wouldn't change or update anything package related so close to submission.

Comment: Thanks for the help, as of one hour ago, the thesis has been submitted for printing now. I went with the suggested modification to the "Fancy stuff" code block, which looked OK, as far as I could tell.

Comment: @JohanA Llongyfarchiadau! (Congratulations!)